# How to trust an applet forever

Tags: java, security, ssl, applet, user-permissions

I have written an applet that needs to use NetworkManager class. Said applet will only be executed in known kiosks of us, and I will put these kiosks into separate places. And the applet needs to be executed without a notification, or without blocking the whole site.

Now the question: even if I created a self-signed certificate and signed the JAR with it, it does ask to get permissions (or to get executed) every now and then.

I put the certificate into kiosks and tried to add them as trusted via Java settings.
I also added the applet location and the location that calls the applet (root URLs) as trusted websites via Java settings, and nothing changed.

[image]

I am not good at Java, therefore any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Java Applet & Web Start - Code Signing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html), [New security requirements for RIAs in 7u51 (January 2014)](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias) and [Signed Code FAQ - Security Manifest Changes](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/signed_code.xml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now the question: even if I created a self-signed certificate and signed the JAR with it, it does ask to get permissions (or to get executed) every now and then.

Yes, I believe this is documented behavior. From [Signed Code FAQ - Security Manifest Changes](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/signed_code.xml).

> **Why don't I see the option to select Do not show this again for this app in the security dialog for an unsigned application?**
>
> Starting with Java 7 Update 40, the option to select Do not show this
>   again for this app is no longer available. Unlike previous versions a
>   user cannot suppress the security dialog for an unsigned application
>   and will have to select the option, I accept the risk and want to run
>   this app, each time to run the unsigned application.

---

You might also be able to distribute the self signed to your kiosks so they are trusted. See [Self-signed certificates for a known community](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/self_signed_certificates_for_a). And also see [Upcoming Exception Site List in 7u51](http://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/upcoming_exception_site_list_in).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I think I am going to install an older version of Java that supports this option.